# Auto-fill parent and grandparent ids in grandchild form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, form-for

I have three Scaffolds: Countries, States, and Districts.

My Routes:

```
NetworkManager::Application.routes.draw do
    root to: "countries#index"
    resources :countries
    resources :states
    resources :districts    
end
```

From countries I go to states. When I go back from states I want it to take me to the parent country. Same with States <-> Districts.

I know how to insert the country link from state using `country_path(@state.country_id)`
I'm having trouble automatically inserting the correct Country and State into the State and District form_for automatically. I don't want the user to have to select the country and state every time since they create a new state from the Country view and they create a new District from the State view.

So, how do I pass the Country and State ids to form_for?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your routes are set up appropriately:

```
resources :countries do
  resources :states
end

resources :states do
  resources :districts
end
```

(which I know they are from your previous question)

```
form_for [@country, @state]
```

Which translates to country_and_state_path(@country, @state).

The array depends on your nesting.  If you're doing two deep as recommended you can just keep that pattern going down the line:

```
form_for [@state, @district]
```

etc.  If not, then something like:

```
form_for [@country, @state, @district]
```

Would also work.  So, that's the pattern there -- depends on your routes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I actually decided to not use any nesting for these ones and instead go with individual paths for each and then just setup the links between them. More info in a separate answer. And maybe you can give me a recommendation on a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I've solved this problem. Albeit, not in my preferred way:

I'll explain this by describing how I add a district to a state since that's the more complex one.

State - show.html.erb (new path code only) Sets the GET parameters to the state's id and country_id, preferably I want to send these in some other manner, but I need to send both.

```
<td colspan=4>
    <%= 
    link_to 'New District', 
    new_district_path(
        :country_id => @state.country_id, 
        :state_id => @state.id
    )
    %>
</td>
```

District - new.html.erb (sets the country_id and state_id to the instances values or to the parameters passed... I'd like to use POST to send those parameters instead)

```
<h1>New district</h1>

<%
@district.country_id = @district.country_id || params[:country_id] || ""
@district.state_id = @district.state_id || params[:state_id] || ""
%>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', state_path(params[:state_id]) %>
```

District - _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@district) do |f| %>
  <% if @district.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@district.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this district from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @district.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :country_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :state_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Does a state not belong to a country?  If so, then the district does not directly need to know what country it belongs to, it just needs to know the state.  It can determine the country via the state (district.state.country).  I get that you may want the form control on the page to allow a user to change their state, perhaps, but the state should give you enough information to do everything.  So, perhaps there's room to simplify things there.  Also, can a district exists with a nil state?  If not, then you really don't need to pass the state either, as any existing district will have a state.

Comment: The issue I was trying to solve is that when a user creates a new district the field for state wasn't auto-filling because I wasn't being able to pull in the state id. I suppose I could make each one be a sub-route to the previous and just deal with parent-child relationships. The only place I'm pulling in the country is in to the form because I ask for it. But I don't necessarily need it. I'm actually making it where every child knows every ancestor currently. Maybe I should switch it to just be parent-child. If I do that, is it better to use nested routes than passing the variable how I am?

Comment: You would eventually need to pass the variables if you are looking higher than two levels (i.e. find country for a district). It's not mutually exclusive in that regard.  The only thing the hierarchy does for you is help when creating new entities, as it presumes you would make a new entity within the context of a parent (i.e. make a new district from an existing state page).  But for show/edit, you don't neeeeed the hierarchy.

Comment: Instead of using the two-level hierarchy is this a way to pass the parent variable without using the GET parameters (e.g. ?country_id=1)

Comment: Not for creating new entities.  Once the entities exist, though, you can access the associations via the model itself (since they will have been created & saved).  But for making new ones, you'll need to somehow know what should be associated.  Of course, if you want users to choose that information on the new page itself, that, too, is an option.  But otherwise, those are pretty much your options AFAIK.

Comment: Interesting. So I'm assuming the better practice is the method you list below in your Answer? Rather than passing the Country, State, District, etc. to each scaffold, just pass the immediate parent.

Comment: Yes, I would say so. Based on what I know of your project, I think that will work well for you, and if you encounter further troubles down the line, it's a more standard approach so it would be easiest to find further assistance or debug.  But, of course, just my opinion; one size doesn't always fit all, so whatever solution works best for your case is what I would say is the "better practice."  :) But yes, I'd recommend that pattern below.